# Remove all content between <script type="JavaScript">abcd</script> tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to remove all things or content between `<script>want to remove</script>`
I have very small amount of knowledge about php & java script so please give me a complete codes I have no idea how to use php or JavaScript coding to remove content between `<tags></tags>`

I found this box and copy in my website they remove all tags but I not want this I want only remove content between tags.
Please any one modify this box or script to remove content between `<tags></tags>` or give me other script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Strip HTML Tags (form) script- By JavaScriptKit.com (http://www.javascriptkit.com)
// For this and over 400+ free scripts, visit JavaScript Kit- http://www.javascriptkit.com/
// This notice must stay intact for use

function stripHTML(){
var re= /<\S[^><]*>/g
for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
arguments[i].value=arguments[i].value.replace(re, "")
}

</script>

<form>

<textarea name="data1" style="width: 400px; height: 100px"></textarea><br />
<input type="button" value="Remove any HTML tags" onClick="stripHTML(this.form.data1)">
</form>
```

Comment: So do I understand correctly that if the textarea 'data1' contains e.g. `Hello <tag>thisisnotwanted</tag> world!` it should contain `Hello <tag></tag> world!` after the button click?

Answer (score 1):

you could try:
  document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].innerHTML = '';

Comment: The cliet side is the dark side!

Comment: Never underestimate the power of the client side. Sometimes security is a non-issue, and sometimes it is necessary to do everything on the client-side. For example - removing or changing the code after it has run. Although - generally I would agree with you in principle, give out code on a need to know basis, optimized, obfuscated and zipped up.

Comment: The client side is also sometimes the _only_ side, as in the case of a Phonegap mobile app. Something I used in such an app is to sanitize scripts from downloaded content with JQuery is `var cleanHtml = $(dirtyHtml).html()`

Answer (score 1):

According to your code block you posted, it seems that you would like to strip script tags from the value of a form element (e.g. a textarea). Sanitizing user input on client side is generally considered to be a bad idea, because this kind of security measure can be easily bypassed. A better solution would be stripping the script tags from the posted data on the server side.

Here is an example in php:

```
$data = $_POST['fieldname'];

$outputData = strip_tags($data, array(/* here you can specify the allowed html tags, all others will be stripped */);

echo $output;
```